# Relationship between intelligence, thinking and knowledge

Tags: meaning

A quick google search defines intelligence as "the ability to acquire and apply knowledge" and thinking as "the process of considering or reasoning about something"

What is the relationship between intelligence and thinking?

Is thinking the thing you do to acquire and apply knowledge and if so how does intelligence fit into it?

PS - The background to this question is in regards to design thinking and design intelligence for a uni course.   Taking design out of the question I am trying to get to bottom of what thinking and intelligence is.  A simple concrete example to put it into context would be brilliant.

Comment: It sounds as if this would be better on Philosophy.SE: if you are really asking about the words, please edit in whattyour research has found.

Comment: Neither "design thinking" nor "design thinking" mean anything to me. But when I google those terms they seem to be ***domain-specific*** to architecture. Whatever they mean, I think the question is Off Topic, since it's not about "standard" use of English.

Comment: @TimLymington - Good point will post on philosophy also - didn't even know that existsed!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Sorry yes, ignore design thinking / intelligence - I just wanted to give a little background to why I was asking the question.  I want to know more about thinking and intelligence themselves.

Comment: @Jonny: Well, there's no real consensus as to what "intelligence" is. It's often said that the only thing IQ tests measure is the ability to score highly on IQ tests, for example. And in *my* opinion, at least, most of what people call "thinking" is either just emoting, or post facto justification for actions or decisions taken as part of an emotional response. You can't get to the bottom of this through dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That is a great comment and would explain why the more I tried to pin it down, the more it eluded me.  The post facto justification definition of thinking is really though provoking too.

Comment: [Human Behavioral Biology](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL848F2368C90DDC3D)

Comment: Knowledge is knowing two numbers, thinking is adding them together, intelligence is understanding what the sum represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FumbleFingers points out in the comments a dictionary is unlikely to help us very much, so perhaps an unscientific analogy would serve.

It is reasonable to imagine the human mind as a computer, which has discrete aspects that somewhat match the words in your question.

**Intelligence** - This generally refers to the processing power of human brain, i.e. the speed and power of the computer's processor and memory.  More intelligence equates to a faster processor and memory.

**Thinking/Reason** - This is similar to the software running on the computer.  It can be well written and bug free, or full of errors and slow.  It's quality is largely independent of the speed of the computer, but there is a relationship.  A highly intelligent person may employ poor reasoning more quickly than a less intelligent person.

**Knowledge** - This is similar to the data stored on the computer.  A brand new computer has limited functionality until it accumulates data to work with, and both intelligence and reason need data to operate upon.

Good luck with your course; please do not cite this answer =).